# What function is it?

Tags: mathematics, pattern

A function of one variable $y = f(x)$. However, I suspect that the function does not need to necessarily be strictly mathematical.

If $x = 1$, then $y = 0$.

If $x = 2$, then $y = 0$.

If $x = 10$, then $y = 9$.

If $x = 3$, then $y = 3$.

If $x = 20$, then $y = 18$.

If $x = 1990$, then $y = 1989$.

What function is it? (A puzzle from an old informatics textbook which I was unable to solve for years.)

Comment: The "old informatics textbook" seems to be from around 1990, since the authors of such problems often use the current year as a "sufficiently large" integer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like

> $y = 3 \lfloor \frac{x}{3} \rfloor$

where

> $\lfloor . \rfloor$ is the floor function indicating the greatest integer less than or equal to the argument.

Similarly

> $y$ is the greatest integer $\leq x$ which is divisible by $3$.

Given that it comes from an informatics textbook Bubbler make an important point that

> some programming is relevant here (and it must be C if it's from 1990):
>  `int f(int x) { return x / 3 * 3; }`

Comment: Great! You beat me for less than a minute.

Comment: Given that it's from an informatics textbook, I guess some programming is relevant here (and it must be C if it's from 1990): `int f(int x) { return x / 3 * 3; }`

Comment: @Bubbler that's a good point, I may add that into the answer (with credit) if that's okay as it provides good context.

Comment: @hexomino Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative (and very similar) answer (which still fits):

> $f(x) = x - L_{10}(x) \bmod 3$, where $L_{10}(x)$ is the leftmost (nonzero as usual) digit of $x$ written in decimal (i.e. $L_{10}(534)=5, L_{10}(6207)=6$ etc.). (The hexomino's answer is simply $f(x)=x-x\bmod3$).